# About using conjugation in $S_4$ to help in finding the outer automorphisms of $D_4$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, dihedral-groups

I'm studying the ${\rm Aut}(D_n)$ from other posts here, even if not all of them are so easy to me but I'm trying to collect them all and get a good view about them.

It's clear ${\rm Inn}(D_4)\cong D_4/Z(D_4)$, which leads to to a group isomorphic to $V_4$.
So there will be then remaining four outer automorphisms leading to $Aut(D_4)\cong D_4$.

Considering $D_4$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$, I was wondering if using the conjugation of $D_4$ in $S_4$ could give any hints to estimate the other four outer automorphisms.

It's just an intution, but I may be wrong of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $S_4$ won't help, since $D_4$ is selfnormalizing in $S_4$. It is more useful to embed $D_4$ in $D_8$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki, thank for your hint, I will try to follow It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think conjugations in $S_4$ will not help to find all automorphisms of the group $D_4$. But to calculate all automorphisms it is indeed useful to know that the subgroup
$$
H=\operatorname{gr}((1324),(12)(34))\cong D_4.
$$
For the group $H$ there are the following $4$ pairs of generating involutions:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (12),(13)(24);\\
(12),(14)(23);\\
(34),(13)(24);\\
(34),(14)(23).
 \end{eqnarray*}
Since every automorphism of the group $H$ is obviously uniquely defined if we know the image of any of these pairs.
Here are 8 automorphisms:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_1(12)=(12),\phi_1((13)(24))=(13)(24);\\
\phi_2(12)=(12),\phi_2((13)(24))=(14)(23);\\
\phi_3(12)=(34),\phi_3((13)(24))=(13)(24);\\
\phi_4(12)=(34),\phi_4((13)(24))=(14)(23);\\
\phi_5(12)=(13)(24),\phi_5((13)(24))=(12);\\
\phi_6(12)=(14)(23),\phi_6((13)(24))=(12);\\
\phi_7(12)=(13)(24),\phi_7((13)(24))=(34);\\
\phi_8(12)=(14)(23),\phi_8((13)(24))=(34);\\
\end{eqnarray*}
The first four automorphisms are inner, the last four are outer.

Comment: TX, this Is really Cool, and at least confirms my intuition of using that subgroup from $S_4$, even if the conjugation doesn't enter the picture. Is It correct to claim H Is a permutation representation of $D_4$?

Comment: Rethinking to It: it''s clear why you chose the invokutions as generators, but it''s not clear how you got each automorphism image. Do you Simply used the fact that the automorphism permute the involutions? This Is the same trick used to compute $Aut(S_3)=S_3$, right? So why are not using for any group, finding It permutation representation?

Comment: Yes, you are right. We used the following facts:
1) any automorphism preserves involutions;
2) any automorphism preserves generators;
3) the group $D_4$ is generated by any two noncommuting involutions.

Well, the permutation representation allows us to state instantly that the last four automorphisms are outer, since they do not preserve the cyclic structure of permutations. By the way, the reasoning can be applied to any dihedral group $D_n$. (Note that $S_3\cong D_3$.)

Comment: Tx for confirming it. I was trying to apply it to $S_3$. Currently $S_3$ can be generated by  two involutions, namely ${(1 2), (1 3)}$. But we expect 6 automorphisms there. So have we to take into account $(2 3)$ as well, even if not generating the group? In doing that, we got a transitive permutation by conjugation where each one can be sent into one other, getting $3!$ at last. While on $D_4$ the action was not transitive, giving $8$ elements instead of $4!$. Is this correct, please? So cannot be applied to a generic $S_n$, but to $D_n$ only?

Comment: Ah OK I got it. Combinatorially, just a matter to list all the non-commuting involutions, and then the resulting automorphisms will be twice the number of couples, so $4 \rightarrow 8$ for $D_4$ and $3 \rightarrow 6$ for $S_3$. What I was asking above is: since every group (not only $S_n$ or $D_n$) can be generated by involutions, can we theoretically apply this construction to every group permutation representation simply using the generating non-commuting involutions? This method is by far easier to me than the ones I've always found on other posts.

Comment: I'm assuming you got these permutations as the symmetries of square, in your case taking a square with bottom left corner as 1 and going in CW order could fit. Generating all elements from your generators would give $\{(e, (1234), (1432), (13), (24), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. So the permutation you are enumerating $(12)$ and $(34)$ cannot be gotten using your generators (you cannot swap only 1 and 2 or 3 and 4). How did you got them? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a typo, instead of the cycle $(1234)$ it should be the cycle $(1324)$.
I corrected it.

Comment: That's really a counterintuive way of numbering the vertices :-) Tx

Comment: Yes, you can take the cycle $(1234)$ and the involutions $(13)$, $(24)$, as long as you follow geometric intuition. It was easier for me to correct the cycle